# How do I do tsset with this specific dataset?

Tags: stata, readstata13

My dataset looks like this:

| Country | year | poverty rate | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 1950 | 0.54 | 142 |
| Austria | 1951 | 0.32 | 12441 |
| Austria | 1952 | 0.32 | 12441 |
| Bangladesh | 1950 | 0.11 | 142123123 |
| Bangladesh | 1951 | 0.52 | 1234 |
| Bangladesh | 1952 | 0.32 | 12441 |
| Sri Lanka | 1950 | 0.95 | 4215 |
| Sri Lanka | 1951 | 0.21 | 142421 |
| Sri Lanka | 1952 | 0.32 | 12441 |

I want to do `tsset` so that I can (for example) create a new variable for change in sales per year for each country. When I try to do `tsset country year`, I see "repeated time values within panel". How can I create a new variable that is change in sales per year for each country and year? I have more variables so I would want to be able to specify the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`country` looks like a string variable from here, but if it were then

```
 tsset country year
```

would fail for that reason. So, suppose `country` is a numeric variable with value labels. Then it is essential to follow up the report of repeated observations with say

```
 duplicates list country year 

 duplicates tag country year, gen(tag) 

 edit if tag
```

Then the next step depends on what you see, for example:

1. The duplicates are just junk with missing values on one of those variables. `drop` the junk.
2. Accidental duplicate observations. `drop` the duplicates.
3. Something more serious.

See also FAQ https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/repeated-time-values/